# Automatically creating python script from GUI in Blender

Tags: python, blender

I would like to have a python script be generated automatically from actions in the GUI, such that playing that script would perfectly replicate the whole scene.

The purpose is to be able to go over the actions with a fine tooth comb for later editing and revision.

The idea seems to be intuitive, since every action in Blender has an equivalent Python command (which is displayed as one clicks the various buttons).

One possible solution is to copy & paste the info window.
I have searched for 'history logging', 'history exporting', 'autocreate script', 'actions to file', 'history to file', and many variations on these themes - to no avail.

Comment: I don't know much about Blender, but [this sounds like recording a macro](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Development/Macros_Recorder). There seems to be a "Record Macro as script" option that might be particularly relevant.